# CodeIgniter 4 image manipulation error withFile() null

Tags: image-manipulation

I'm trying to make resize image before posting into my view, but always get this error. I've try using html helper img with same dir address and there's no error and my image displayed. How to fix this? Thanks

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67ork.jpg)